# Google and Yahoo OpenID Endpoint

Tags: openid, google-openid, yahoo-oauth

Are https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id and https://me.yahoo.com are Google's and Yahoo's OpenID Endpoint or the URL's to which I must send the discovery request, which in response will have the OpenID Endpoints?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are discovery url's, not endpoints.

Comment: It's spelled "URLs."

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that format doesn't work, and Yahoo no longer has any documentation on it apparently.